# Changing form field title within hook_preprocess_form() does not work

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I have customize drupal user registration form which I want to change some field titles.

I implemented hook_preprocess_form() within theme and changed titles of some form fields, but it didn't work.

While debugging I found that it has '#children' item already there with rendered HTML inside it. Then I tried to change that value by using drupal_render_children(), but that also doesn't work.

What is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Use `hook_form_alter()` to change the form before it gets rendered.

Comment: I cannot do that because the fields are inserted by other modules using hook_form_alter. It may or may not available within form alter hook depending on the loading order of modules.

Comment: You can change your module's weight in the system table to ensure it gets executed after all the rest. You'll then have everything everytime in your hook.

Comment: In Drupal 7 you can use hook_form_alter in a theme's template.php file. Themes' hooks should always be executed after all modules' hooks.